# Python: How to use requests library to get network data from a website

Tags: python, request, fetch

Every time you enter into a website and you inspect the site, you can see you could get some information like "elements" which contains the html of the website, but also there is some data contained in the "network" tab. I would like to get the Fetch/XHR names of all the contents in the network

```
url = "https://www.jobteaser.com/en"
```

[image]

#### My sample code that does not work properly

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.jobteaser.com/en'
response = requests.get(url)

xhr_names = []
for req in response.history + [response]:
    for xhr in req.request._cookies.values():
        if 'Fetch' in xhr and 'Response' in xhr:
            xhr_names.append(xhr.split('?')[0])

print(xhr_names)
```

#### Expected Response

```
["https://client.axept.io/5fd938934e433a71df9437d3.json?r=0", "metadata", "https://api.axept.io/v1/app/consent/5fd938934e433a71df9437d3?token=v0fd7vbc9l79i8i2ijrwn&service=cookies"]
```